# proof $\forall n \exists p (p^2 \leq n <(p+1)^2)$

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, natural-numbers

how can i prove this?

$\forall n \exists p (p^2 \leq n <(p+1)^2)$

The domain of quantifiers is N.

It came from discrete mathematics, and I don't know how to start proofing.

Comment: This depends entirely on what axioms you are given and what lemmas/theorems you have so far. Also you are unlikely to get answers unless you have shown significant effort and point out where and why you are stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $n$ is a perfect square we can take $p=\sqrt{n}$. If not let $p$ be the largest natural number for which $p^2 < n$. Then $n < (p+1)^2$, since otherwise we get a contradiction on the maximality of $p$.

Comment: Or just take $p=\lfloor\sqrt n\rfloor$.

Comment: I understood the problem that the domains of p and n are natural numbers, but if p is taken as sqrt(n), doesn't it deviate from the domain?

Comment: If $n$ is a perfect square then its square-root is a natural number. If not, we have the floor function.